# Android: ImageView Background Color and Alpha

Tags: android, imageview, background-color, alpha

For an `ImageView` display, I would like to set that the users can set the background color and the alpha. Therefore, I have coded as follows after saving there preference:

### display_tran_seekbar

```
display_tran_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar customSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
            {
                display_tranI = customSeekBar.getProgress();    
                tv_display_bgd_vis.setText("Display Invisibility: " + display_tranI + "%");
                display.setAlpha( (int) (display_tranI * 255 /100 ));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar customSeekBar) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar customSeekBar) 
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = saved_display_transparency.edit();                               
                e.putInt("saved_display_transparency", display_tranI);                    
                e.apply();
            }              
       });
```

### display color:

```
public void save_display_color(int k)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = saved_display.edit();                                
    e.putInt("saved_display", k);                     
    e.apply();
         if (k==1) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_red));}
    else if (k==2) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_orange));}
    else if (k==3) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_yellow));}
    else if (k==4) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_green));}
    else if (k==5) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_blue));}
    else if (k==6) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_purple));}
    else if (k==7) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_pink));}
    else if (k==8) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_brown));}
    else if (k==9) {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_black));}
    else {display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tran_white));}    
}
```

### xml:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_seekbar_display_bgd_vis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_display_default"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_dislay"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/display_tran_seekbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:progress="18" >

                </SeekBar>
```

The alpha can be adjusted by a seekbar using the variable display_alpha_integer, which is working properly. Yet after the user has changed the backgroundcolor sucessfully, further sliding the seekbar does not make any difference to the display imageview.

How could the above be modified?

Comment: if the if statement been called each time you move the seekbar?? also post some code

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply! related full codes posted

Comment: is save_display_color called when seekbar is moved??

Comment: no, seekbar is only for the change of alpha. for the color, there will be 10 color button box for user to press, and invoke save_display_color(k) for which the button is pressed. so alpha and color are independent~

Comment: i have implemented similar for the background image. In that aspect, it is imageview.setBACKGROUND and  then imageview.setalpha (both are independent actions too) and then it works. u may think for example, it is a calculator, the bgd panel can alter its bgd with image and alpha, and the problem here is the display panel on top of calculator, the bgd color and alpha of the display cannot work together. So i am curious whether setBackgroundColor cannot work together with alpha?

Comment: what api are you using?

Comment: and the display_tranI does it return from 0 - 1??

Comment: Yes,  as the way works for bgd image alpha...so dont know whether setbackgroundcolor can work with setalpha,  as the color to be set are already with transparency

Comment: can you post the xml where the seebar is located

Comment: Before adding background color to the image view ..clear the image view background.... By setting setBackgroundColor(0).

Comment: @pearmak i think you can set Alpha Animation in relative layout.